# DataGridCheckBoxColumn not working fine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I just created a DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn ... />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsEditing, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="IsEditing" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My problem is that **when I want to check this checkbox inside record at first the row is selected and only then I can check this checkbox**... It is Very Uncomfortable... And in addition... **event for dependency property of objects for which is created this DataGrid also runs when I will select another row**.

To be more clearly I will explain you step by step:

1. I want to select item which will run event of dependency property.
2. I click on checkbox but insted of cheched only row is selected
3. I must click AGAIN on checbox to check it, but event also doesn't run
4. I must click/select other row to make run event of dependency property of last selected object/row

Why this is working so terrible? Is there any option to make it working more comfortable for user(for me also)?

Comment: I remember this is some about is focusable or something like that.  If you use a checkbox in a templated column then it does not have this same problem.

Comment: What is the reason that you find DataGridTemplateColumn completely unuseful?

Comment: I know I make this work with DataGridCheckBoxColumn.  It might have been hasfocus.  But I am with Skett - why does templated not work?   I got so frustrated with DataGridCheckBoxColumn I just stopped using it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a MouseLeftButtonUp event for the DataGrid:

```
    private void GridMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as DataGrid;

        if (grid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Assume first column is the checkbox column.
        if (grid.CurrentColumn == grid.Columns[0])
        {
            var gridCheckBox = (grid.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(grid.SelectedItem) as CheckBox);

            if (gridCheckBox != null)
            {
                gridCheckBox.IsChecked = !gridCheckBox.IsChecked;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a little outdated or was done from memory, but helped me out - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add Property IsThreeState = "False" to the DataGridCheckBoxColumn